# how to make background image zoomed on small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using this for a site I'm writing

```
.homepage{
 background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/ep/img/_.png);
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:0px @blackbar_height;
}
```

It works fine on big screens, but I'd like to use media query in order to be able to zoom out a certain part of the background image (let's say I'd like to focus the center part) when it's either phone or tablet.

Comment: on mobile use % values instead of cover in `background-size` i.e: `background-size: 50% auto;`

Comment: no, that will just make the image smaller, I want to zoom a part of the image

Comment: then do this:  `background-size: 150% auto; ` and you can use  `background-position ` to focus on a certain part.

Comment: damn, i didn't think about this. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
background-size: 150% auto; // Yes background size can be increased more than 100%.
```

You can use `background-position` to focus on a certain part.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `background-size` the way you want and set `background-position: center` to focus it to the center.

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .homepage {
    background-size: 640px auto;
    background-position: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.zoom {
                -moz-transform:scale(2); 
                -webkit-transform:scale(2);
                -o-transform:scale(2);
            }
```